# freecodecamp вопрос

Tags: javascript

Задача заключается в том что бы вывести самое большое число из массива массива,и запихнуть в отдельный массив. 
У меня получилось так

```
let array = [];
 function largestOfFour(arr) {
    for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        array.push(Math.max(...arr[i]));
    }
        return array;

  }

  console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 9, 1, 3], [13, 35, 18, 26], [32, 35, 97, 39], [1000000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

А это решение сайта

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var results = [];
    for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++) {
      var largestNumber = arr[n][0];
      for (var sb = 1; sb < arr[n].length; sb++) {
        if (arr[n][sb] > largestNumber) {
          largestNumber = arr[n][sb];
        }
      }

      results[n] = largestNumber;
    }

    return results;
  }
```

Так вот , есть идеи почему мой вариант сайт не принимает?Хотя выводит все тоже самое.

---

Сайт - 
https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/return-largest-numbers-in-arrays

Comment: А зачем array объявлен снаружи функции?

Comment: andreymal дело говорит, будучи запущена несколько раз она вернет некорректный результат

Comment: Да вы правы, теперь заработало..

Answer (score 1):

Как одна из версий: ты используешь оператор spread(...), являющийся относительно новым стандартом. Возможно, сайт его не знает